# LXTerminal missing

Tags: raspbian-stretch, vnc, lxterminal

I have Stretch on my Raspberry runnig via VNC-Viewer and everything works fine. But there is no LXTerminal available. In the System Tools menu there is only Termit listed, in the Accessories I see Filemanager, Screenshot and Task Manager.
How can I get LXTerminal? apt-get update changes nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you can't execute `lxterminal`. On Raspbian Stretch, not using the Light version, it is installed by default.

Anyway, if you are missing it you can just install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install lxterminal
```

Comment: Thank you, worked. I installed flask on my system, but never deleted anything. I have no idea where I got Termit.